# Subtract one day from date and find values -Js

Tags: javascript

i working on small billing application using electronjs and pouchdb
i want to find the opening balance for every day based on date selection on input

if there is no data in particular date i want to find the data by the previous dates

i tried in recursive way but it did not work

```js
// getting date value on change
var  TodayDate = document.getElementById('daybook-firstdate').value;

// onchange function
function getday(TodayDate){
   

    daybook.find({
        selector: {
            
            Date:TodayDate ,
           
        }
    }).then(function(result) {  
        
        var opening_balance = 0
       
        //chenking the data is present in  the selected date 
        if(result.docs.length>0){

            result.docs.forEach((element, ) => {

                saletotal = (isNaN(element.TotalAmount) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalAmount));
                Totalinvest = (isNaN(element.TotalInvestment) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalInvestment));
                Totalexp = (isNaN(element.TotalExpenses) ? 0: parseInt(element.TotalExpenses));

                opening_balance+=saletotal+Totalinvest-Totalexp

            
                console.log(opening_balance)

                
            });
        } 
        // if there is no data on particular date subtracting one  day from  date from date and calling the 
        //get day function with yesterday value as parameter to check if the data is present in previos date
        else{

            let d = new Date(TodayDate);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
            var yesterdaydate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];

            getday(yesterdaydate)

        }
        
           
            

        
    });

 
    

}
```

```html
//selecting the date
<input type="date" name="daybook" id="daybook-firstdate" onchange="getday()" >
```

i want to execute the find until there is data in previous date from selected date
any one help me with code

day book object:         //find is based on `Date` object
[image]

Comment: You probably should include a `daybook` example object in your question, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: added the day book object for your reference

Comment: `onchange` is firing off an asynchronous function but it's not awaiting it. Also, you're not returning anything from `getday`. Try adding a return statement before `daybook.find` and the call to `getday` in the else clause.

Comment: if adding return before daybook.find how the daybook,find will execute can you help me with a code